# How to access the elements of a matrix without lists in this example?

Tags: haskell, matrix, dimension

I am quite new at haskell. Our task is to write an algorithm that calculates the dimension of a square matrix. But we are not supposed to use lists. But I dont know how to access to each element of the matrix, which is given like that:

```
matrixA 1 1 = 0
matrixA 1 2 = 42
matrixA 1 3 = 1337
matrixA 2 1 = 501
matrixA 2 2 = 314
matrixA 2 3 = 301
matrixA 3 1 = 13
matrixA 3 2 = 161
matrixA 3 3 = 271
matrixA _ _ = -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the element of the matrix at row `i` and column `j`, you can simply use `matrixA i j`. In fact, `matrixA` is a function which maps both indexes to the matrix element.

I guess that the last `-1` case represents an invalid value, meaning "indexes outside the matrix". So, it seems that to find the size you just have to query the matrix with larger and larger row/column indexes until you get `-1`. A basic way to solve that is to proceed recursively.